# SQL padding 0 to the left of a number in string

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, padding

I am a beginner in SQL language and I am using postgre sql and doing little exercices to learn. I have a column of strings named acronym from a destination table:

```
 DO1
 ES1
 ES2
 FR1
 FR10
 FR2
 FR3
 FR4
 FR5
 FR6
 FR7
 FR8
 FR9
 GP1
 GP2
 IN1
 IN2
 MU1
 RU1
 TR1
 UA1
```

I would like to add a padding zero for acronym numbers that have only one digit, output:

```
 DO01
 ES01
 ES02
 FR01
 FR02
 FR03
 FR04
 FR05
 FR06
 FR07
 FR08
 FR09
 FR10
 GP01
 GP02
 IN01
 IN02
 MU01
 RU01
 TR01
 UA01
```

How can I get to the left of the first number in the string? There is some regex I think but I did not figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string functions like `lpad()`, `substr()`, `left()`:

```
select 
  concat(left(columnname, 2), lpad(substr(columnname, 3), 2, '0')) result
from tablename
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fLKSn7B1fK6DdGxuZTkvdJ/2).
Results:

```
| result |
| ------ |
| DO01   |
| ES01   |
| ES02   |
| FR01   |
| FR10   |
| FR02   |
| FR03   |
| FR04   |
| FR05   |
| FR06   |
| FR07   |
| FR08   |
| FR09   |
| GP01   |
| GP02   |
| IN01   |
| IN02   |
| MU01   |
| RU01   |
| TR01   |
| UA01   |
```

Comment: great, could you explain what lpad(substr(columnname, 3), 2, '0') does exactly ?

Comment: `substr(columnname, 3)` returns everything from the 3d char to the end of the column value and `lpad` makes sure that this returned string is exactly 2 chars long filled at the left with 0 if needed. You can read this: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-lpad/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`rpad()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) function to add characters to the *end* of the value:

```
select rpad(col, '0', 4)
```

In your case, though, you want a value in-between.  On simple method is -- assuming that the first two characters are strings -- is:

```
(case when length(col) = 3
      then left(col, 2) || '0' || right(col, 1)
      else col
 end)
```

Another possibility is using `regexp_replace()`:

```
regexp_replace(col, '^([^0-9]{2})([0-9])$', '\10\2')
```

Both of these assume that the strings to be padded are three characters, which is consistent with your data.  It is unclear what you want for other lengths.

Comment: @sql . . . I had noticed that just as you were writing the comment.

Comment: I'd use regexp. For the given sample data it could even be `replace(col, '^(..)(.)$', '\10\2')`.

Answer (score 1):

try with below:

`to_char()` function

```
select to_char(column1, 'fm000') as column2
from Test_table;
```

`fm` "fill mode"prefix avoids leading spaces in the resulting var char. 
`000` it defines the number of digits you want to have.

Comment: Accordint to the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) `to_char(text, text)` doesn't exist.